# problem in placing three text view horizontally in android

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

in my app i have placed three text view horizontally in a linear layout. Two text view at the corner of the layout and they are fixed and will not be changed. I have On Click listener over the layout to move to a next activity. In the second activity whatever i type in an edit box will be placed in middle text view.

Now the problem is the first text view is in the corner but the if the length of the middle text view is short the third text view gets changed or if the middle text view is too large the third one gets disturbed.

I want the first and third to be at the corners and the middle one to get adjusted automatically according to its text size. How to do this please help me...

Following is my layout

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/inputLayout1">
                          <TextView android:textSize="22sp" android:text="Input Type" android:id="@+id/inputtext1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                          <TextView  android:textSize="22sp" android:text="GPS" android:id="@+id/inputtext2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                          <TextView  android:textSize="22sp" android:text="A" android:id="@+id/inputtext3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You may want to add android:weightSum = 4 to the Linearlayout and then for 1 and 3 make android:layout_weight = 1 and android:layout_weight = 2 for the 2nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with the previous two suggestions, and I don't think they address what the questioner is looking to do.

I think something along the following lines is what's sought.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="left text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="very long middle text, very long middle text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="right text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF777777"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="left text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="short middle text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="right text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="left text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="short middle text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="longer right text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/inputLayout1">
                          <TextView android:textSize="22sp" android:text="Input Type" android:id="@+id/inputtext1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                          <TextView  android:textSize="22sp" android:text="GPS" android:id="@+id/inputtext2" android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                          <TextView  android:textSize="22sp" android:text="A" android:id="@+id/inputtext3"  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                      </LinearLayout>
```

adjust the weights accordingly to size the textviews.

Comment: Note that for the middle text to ellipsize instead of just truncate, change the lines="1" attribute to singleLine="true", and then you can optionally also change how it ellipsizes with the ellipsize attribute.